# Find what button was clicked inside a Gridview ASP.Net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, gridview

I have a gridview named gvappts.
This grid has seven columns one for each day of the week.
The grid also has multiple rows, each cell has a button inside.

If I am using an onRowCommand event is there a way to find the name of the button that was clicked?

I started off with this:

```
if (e.CommandName == "GetData")
{
    //Get rowindex
    int rowindex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    //Get Row
    GridViewRow gvr = gvappts.Rows[rowindex];
}
```

not sure if I am going about this quite right.

Here is a snippet for the gridview on the web page, all the columns are using TemplateFields.

```
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField   HeaderText="Day 1" HeaderStyle-CssClass= "hdr" ItemStyle-CssClass="Grid">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:LinkButton id="lbd1" runat="server" Text='<%#(Eval("Day1"))%>' CommandName="GetData" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>'/>
        </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Comment: Can you post the markup for the gridview?

Comment: You can add an onclick event to the button itself instead of using commanding. Then in your onclick just cast your sender as a button to get its details.

Comment: Use FindControl something like this.LinkButton lbtn = (LinkButton)GridView1.FindControl("btnLink"); OR
Check on the sender. LinkButton lb = (LinkButton)sender;

Comment: @jmag, no you couldn't. In a `RowCommand` the sender is the GridView, not the LinkButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `CommandSource` and cast it back to a LinkButton.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lb = e.CommandSource as LinkButton;
    string value = lb.CommandArgument;
}
```

Comment: To add one thing to this if you want to just find the ID of the button clicked you can do this  -----  string value = lb.ID;